# Is is possible to move from (a,b) to (c,d)

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, dynamic-programming

The problem was to output whether it is possible to move from a given point `(a,b)` to target `(c,d)`

We are restricted to positive co-ordinates only

The following two moves are possible

```
(a,b) -> (a+b,b)
(a,b) -> (a,b+a)
```

For instance, `(1,1)` to `(5,4)` is `True`
You can do the following: Using 2nd move 3 times, `(1,1) -> (1,2) -> (1,3) -> (1,4)` Using 1st move 1 time `(1,4) -> (5,4)` 
I came up with the following recursive method

```
def move(a,b,c,d):
    if a==c and b==d:
        return True
    elif a>c or b>d:
        return False
    else:
        ans = False
        if a < c:
            if move(a+b,b,c,d):
                return True
        if b < d:
            if move(a,b+a,c,d):
                return True
    return False
```

a) Does my solution cover all the possible cases. I am unable to verify for sure since I do not have test cases, but I think I did take everything into account.

b) What is the time complexity of my solution? I think it is exponential but can't say for sure.

c) Is there a better solution to this (in terms of time complexity). Can we use dynamic programming?

Thank you for any input.

Comment: i think you could optimize it abit by `elif a>c or b>d:`instead of `and`

Comment: @ScottSauyet yes sorry. fixed

Comment: I don't think your solution covers all cases, what about: (1, -1) -> (0, -1)

Comment: So the question is: do the numbers have to be positive?  If so, I think there's a much faster solution.

Comment: @ScottSauyet does it involve GCD?

Comment: @גלעדברקן: No, although that's related.  You can't get from (3, 5) to (6, 7), even though both have the same gcd.

Comment: @ScottSauyet yes only positive coordinates

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If all the numbers have to be positive, then I believe there is a much quicker solution.

Trying to find if we can get from `(a, b)` to, say `(14, 31)`, we can note that the only way with positive numbers to reach `(14, 31)` is to apply the second rule to `(14, 17)`.  The only way to get to `(14, 17)` is to apply the second rule to `(14, 3)`.  The only way to get to `(14, 3)` is to apply the first rule to `(11, 3)`.  The only way to `(11, 3)` is to apply the first rule to `(8, 3)`, and so on.  So the only values that can reach `(14, 31)` are

```
(14, 31) # Final
(14, 17) # Rule 2
(14, 3)  # Rule 2
(11, 3)  # Rule 1
(8, 3)   # Rule 1
(5, 3)   # Rule 1
(2, 3)   # Rule 1
(2, 1)   # Rule 2
(1, 1)   # Rule 1
```

So an algorithm is pretty simple.  Loop on `(c, d)`, replacing it with `(c - d, d)` if `c > d` and with `(c, d - c)` if `c < d`, stopping when you hit a match, when `c == d`, when `c < a` or `d < b`.

A variant of this described in a comment by Paul Hankin is `O(log n)`, although I'm not going to try to prove it.  This version is `O(n)`, where `n` is the larger of `c` and `d`.  Consecutive Fibonacci numbers will probably take the most steps.

Of course all this is meaningless if you can have negative numbers, since the first rule applied to `(-17, 31)` would also yield `(14, 31)` and you're back to exponential.

Comment: It seems O(n) in the worst case, for example from `(1, 1)` to `(1, n)`. Nice simple solution anyway

Comment: It's not log(n) since for example (n,1) to (1,1) takes n-1 steps. But it can be, if you apply all repeated applications of a rule in one go: (c, d) -> (c%d, d) or (c, d%c). You have to be careful to note when you've skipped over the target, but that's not difficult to incorporate.

Comment: @PaulHankin: yes, I did have that in mind when I thought through the time complexity, but decided the question should only get the simpler answer.  Then I forgot to restate the complexity.  Updating to make this clear.

Comment: @ScottSauyet say your Final is (10,10). You can reach this via (0,10) as well as (10,0). In this case how do you decide which rule to apply?

Comment: @hsnd: But the numbers have to be positive, so zero is out.  So you can stop at `(10, 10)`.  That's why I said we stop when `c = d`.  If we need to include zero, it's a minor modification to handle the one oddball case of `c = d`.

Answer (score 0):

Answers:

a. Yeah, it covers all cases.

b. It's complexity is exponential as from every state it tries to go to all the remaining states.

c. Yes, you can use dynamic programming by memoizing dp[a][b];

Initialie *dp[][]* all to -1;

```
def move(a,b,c,d):
    // memoizing is here.
    if dp[a][b] != -1
        return dp[a][b];
    dp[a][b] = INF; // INF = 100000000;
    if a==c and b==d:
        return dp[a][b] = True
    elif a>c and b>d:
        return dp[a][b] = False
    else:
        ans = False
        if a < c:
            if move(a+b,b,c,d):
                return dp[a][b] = True
        if b < d:
            if move(a,b+a,c,d):
                return dp[a][b] = True
    return dp[a][b] = False
```

If you use dynamic programming complexity reduces to O(c*d)